# FBConnect on Drupal not working?

Tags: drupal, fbconnect

I installed the fbconnect module: http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect

According to some advice I got from a post on Drupal: http://drupal.org/node/1060220#comment-4088290, i Should get the latest dev version from here: https://github.com/vectoroc/fbconnect

I got the latest version, and I still have problems. When you click on the FacebookConnect icon, it tells me:

```
fbconnect_autoconnect_form_submit has been called without valid facebook session. Check your Application Secret on fbconnect settings page
```

Keep in mind:

- I am running Drupal of my local machine, so my connect URL is: http://localhost/deals/src/
- I DID enter the correct Application ID
- I DID enter the correct Application Secret

Anybody know why I am still getting this error? Is it even possible to specify your local machine as the connect URL?

Comment: Your session from facebook disconnected, try relogin again from drupal site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook must be able to identify you by your domain name / app id / key. 
So if you want fbconnect to work on your local machine, you have to configure a dyndns entry that refers to your IP and associate it with your facebook app.

This may help : http://drupal.org/node/949248

Comment: There is a good chance I might love you after this. Will test and report back.